# This way to the supermarket

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

An employee is tasked with writing a temporary sign to deal with a diversion. It must be written in English and one other language.

The employee speaks passable English and comes up with the following.

[image]

> To the
>
> Supermarket
>
> Direction
>
> Over here

He heads back to work but realises he forgot to make the second sign. A colleague who would like an excuse to go out for a few minutes volunteers to do the translation. She sees the first notice and uses Google translate for the second language.

On the way home, the manager sees the notice and is impressed at what she takes to be the ingenuity of the second sign-writer.

What is the name of the supermarket? What country does the action take place in? Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the supermarket

> ASDA?

If we put the text into Google Translate and translate it into

> Spanish

We get:

> Al
> Supermercado
> Dirección
> Aqui

The manager thought the ingenuity was:

> The first letter of each line spells out "ASDA", which is the name of a British supermarket chain, so the story must take place in the UK

Comment: You are very nearly there. This is correct in essence but  doesn't take into account one very specific detail I put in the question. I can also make a quibble about your version of the new sign.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK edited the answer, is that what you meant?

Comment: Should've gone a few languages further down the list...